# Invalid JSON Response while connecting DApp, Metamask and Backend

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

I am getting some error(picture below) while trying to connect DApp with a backend.  One day ago, everything worked fine, now I got an error: **"basic auth failure"**. Contracts are deployed on Ropsten Test Network, of course using truffle. Although the message is presented, I am unable to debug it further. Any helpful guides or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was actually in providing a HTTP Provider. I provided it twice, first one in truffle.js and second one in one of VueJS Components I created. So pay attention on it.

Answer found: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64121/50548). Thanks to [abed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/42143/abed) for the tip.